# Transposing the output of a CSV from rows to columns in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, reducers

```
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/jrobertsonpanthera/surveyed_grid_3test")

// Hansen Data
var gfc = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2022_v1_10')
var lossImage = gfc.select(['loss'])
var lossAreaImage = lossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())

var lossYear = gfc.select(['lossyear'])

var lossByYearCollection = lossAreaImage
  .addBands(lossYear)
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: aoi, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({groupField: 1}),
    scale: 30
  })
  
var stats = lossByYearCollection
  .map(function (feature) {
    var id = feature.get('id')
    var groups = ee.List(feature.get('groups'))
    return ee.FeatureCollection(groups.map(function(el) {
      var d = ee.Dictionary(el)
      return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), {
        id: id,
        year: ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), 
        area: d.get('sum')
      })
    }))
  })
  .flatten()

print(stats,'stats')

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: stats, 
  description: 'loss-area-by-polygon-and-year', 
  selectors: ['id, year, area'] // If don't want the .geo and system:index columns
})

//show aoi, zoom the map
Map.addLayer(ee.Image().paint(aoi, 1, 3), null, 'region'); 
Map.centerObject(aoi,9);

//show the loss layer
var treeLossVisParam = {
  bands: ['lossyear'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['yellow', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(gfc, treeLossVisParam, 'tree loss year');
```

In the code above (and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465363/how-to-map-a-grouped-reducer-over-a-feature-collection)), I have a grouped reducer that is getting the annual mean value from the yearloss band of the Hansen Forest Change dataset, mapping over a feature collection, and outputting a CSV as shown below. There is a row for each year (2000-2022) and the associated id of each vector feature in the FC:

Printed FeatureCollection:

[image]

Output CSV:

[image: values in rows]

I'm trying to transpose this data so that have a row for each id and columns for each year of data:

[image]

I've had success with this when mapping over an image collection with bands for each year, with something like this:

```
var AnnualImg = ee.ImageCollection(ICAnnual.iterate( 
  function (image, previous) {
    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
  },
  ee.Image([])));
  
var FCReduced = ee.Image(AnnualImg) 
    .reduceRegions({
      collection: aoi,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 463.313,
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    });
```

but I'm struggling to change this format of the FeatureCollection so my CSV has columns instead of rows for each year. What am I missing about how this grouped reducer differs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you might want to map over the aoi collection and use `reduceRegion()` instead of using `reduceRegions()`. Then it's a matter of fiddling to turn years into columns - I don't know a very simple way to do this. I tend to turn the data into an array and transpose it.

```
var stats = aoi.map(function (feature) {
  var tuples = ee.List(lossAreaImage
    .addBands(lossYear)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({groupField: 1}),
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
    .get('groups')
  ).map(function (group) {
    group = ee.Dictionary(group)
    var year = group.getNumber('group').add(2000)
    var area = group.getNumber('sum')
    return [year, area]
  })
  var yearsAreas = ee.Array(tuples).transpose()
  var years = yearsAreas
    .slice(0, 0, 1)
    .project([1])
    .toList()
    .map(function (year) {
      return ee.Number(year).format('loss_%d')
    })
  var areas = yearsAreas
    .slice(0, 1)
    .project([1])
    .toList()
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), ee.Dictionary.fromLists(years, areas))
    .set('id', feature.get('id'))
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f91f33d6c7a93d4e354e181254db5f14